# comercial idea for a gpl project

Tags: open-source, code-generation

i have a code generator project i would like to offer like open source, but giving programmers the option to get some money writing plugins, anyone having experience about how to do it?

for example im thinking in doing some kind of packets or plugins to add to the application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the GPL, that could be tricky.

But other open-source licenses (Apache, MIT, or BSD for example) allow derived commercial products.

Comment: thanks Thilo, but im not talking about type of licenses but an programatic way to do it , i mean licensing by software, for example using the licensing way of .net, excuse my bad english